# How to check containment in a django arrayfield?

Tags: python, django

I am working with django models in Python where one of a model's fields is a ArrayField of id's, and, given a specific instance of a model with an ArrayField as a field, I want to check if a given id is in that instance's ArrayField. I have tried doing `x in self.exampleArrayField` but I get `Value 'self.exampleArrayField' doesn't support membership test` I have also tried `x in list(self.exampleArrayField)` but I have no idea if this even works (my editor, vscode, doesn't throw an error, but this is Python I'm working in). Is there a good way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use ORM methods to achieve this.

For an example, check out [the documentation on ArrayFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains)

We have this model

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

To find posts that are tagged as "django"

```
>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__contains=['django'])
<QuerySet [<Post: First post>, <Post: Third post>]>
```

Here `tags__contains` expands to a special filter that actually queries within the array using PostgreSQL features.

**Alternatively** you can use the [under-documented `to_python` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/47379d027ba2786403969367ec9c721936a823f8/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py#L111).

Which for your example would be:

```
x in self.exampleArrayField.to_python()
```

However, **take a hard look at your code** and consider if this is really necessary. If you are looping over a bunch of Python objects and calling this method, you are losing 100% of the performance benefits of Postgres operating on the arrays using the ORM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw that example, but what I am trying to do is, given a specific instance of a model, check if it's array field contains a given think (in this case a string). I don't see any way of querrying the whole db to check this, besides querrying all the instances of the model containing the string, and then checking if any of them equal my given instance, but that seems horribly inefficient. Is there a better way than what I see to do what I'm talking about? Thanks again btw!

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, the to_python() function seems to require a list value as an input, according to the documentation given. what should I give it?